# Returning the last value from the FILTER function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets and would like to get the last value in column when it is filtered based on the values in a separate column as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of example spreadsheet]

I'd like to get the last value from column A, where the value in column B matches that specified in cell D1.

I've managed to do this with the following:

`=INDEX(FILTER($A:$A,$B,$B=$D$1),COUNTA(FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B-$D$1)),1)`

This works but it seems unnecessary to have the second FILTER and COUNTA as it makes it harder to understand. Is there no way I can just return the last value from the FILTER function?

Since posting this I've found another way that's more concise, but I have to confess I don't actually understand how it works:

`=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($B:$B=$D$1),$A:$A))`

Comment: Wish you have been posted it as an answer. (it took me a while to find what you did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a way that I do that sometimes.  it takes advantage of the VLOOKUP(....TRUE) [default] option.

=VLOOKUP(9^99,FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},B:B=D1),2)

Comment: And it's even simpler if you happen to have a timestamp column in your real data.

Comment: This works for me in the example, but when I try it on real data I get the following error:
Did not find value '2.95127E+94' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: what happens when you just try this part.  =FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},B:B=D1)  ?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, I'd managed to switch the arguments to the array construction inside the curly brackets. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Here you will know about sort and array_Constrain:

```
=array_constrain(filter(sort({A1:A,row(A1:A)},2,false),B1:B=D1),1,1)
```

or you can use query:

```
=query(filter({A1:A,row(A1:A)},B1:B=D1),"Select Col1 order by Col2 desc limit 1")
```

or you can use indirect:

```
=indirect("A" & max(filter(row(A:A),B:B=D1)))
```

Comment: The last 2 work for me, but I can't get the first array_constrain formula to work - is there an error in it?

If I'm understanding what you're doing correctly I can get it to work with index:
`=index(filter(sort({A1:A,row(A1:A)},2,false),B1:B=D1),2,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use the REDUCE function

```
=REDUCE("", FILTER($A:$A,$B,$B=$D$1), LAMBDA(accumulator, current_value, current_value))
```

Comment: What lambda syntax is that with three arguments?